# Asserting type family forall equalities

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm getting errors roughly like this:

```
Could not deduce T1 p (T2 p a b) ~ (a, b)
```

from a function declaration, where `T1` and `T2` are type families.

However, the equality is true for all `p`, `a` and `b`.

I can fix it by adding:

```
T1 p (T2 p a b) ~ (a, b)
```

But then I get something like the following:

```
Could not deduce T1 p (T2 p a c) ~ (a, c)
```

Eventually I can add enough equality constraints to the function to kill the error.

The alternative is to not define a function signature, the compiler derives something horrific, but it works fine.

But is there a way I can say something like

```
forall p a b. T1 p (T2 p a b) ~ (a, b)
```

So I can just cover these all in one go?

Comment: What were `T1` and T2` by the way?

Comment: Please add a complete example of what you're trying to do. This question is not answerable as it stands.

Comment: "following equality is true" -- how do you know that it is true? Is the question about proving to GHC it is such so that you can omit the type equality constraint in your type signatures?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your difficulty is that your statement

> [The] equality is true for all `p`, `a`, and `b`.

is not quite true. Your claimed equality is

```
T1 p (T2 p a b) ~ (a, b)
```

Suppose I give you

```
type family P :: k
type family A :: k
type family B :: k
```

where none of the familIes have any instances. Will `T1 P (T2 P A B)` still reduce to `(A, B)`? If so, I believe GHC should accept your function with no context. If not, you'll have to pass in some evidence. For example, you could pass evidence that each type is or isn't of a certain form. Under a pattern match, and maybe with some extra help, the family should reduce.